# Reuse a single Fragment in a Viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, okhttp

I have a `BlogActivity` which has 7 tabs.I have created a single `BlogCategoryFragment` which I want to re-use or recycle when a user scrolls/switches the tabs.
Example when the user switches to News tab,the `BlogCategoryFragment` will be used to display News items,when the user switches to another tab the `BlogCategoryFragment` fetches different articles.
[See the Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ7Sx.png)
All the items to be fetched in different tabs share a single `BlogModel` model.
The problems are:
1.Data in the first Tab does not load.
2.Other tabs can load the data though a single item would appear in the recycleView several times.
3.At a times scrolling would stop the app.

Here is my code:
**BlogActivity**

```
public class BlogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blog);
        //viewpager initialization
        BlogCategoryStatePagerAdapter blogCategoryStatePagerAdapter;
        blogCategoryStatePagerAdapter = new BlogCategoryStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.blog_container);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(blogCategoryStatePagerAdapter);


        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.blog_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        //end viewpager
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
   public class BlogCategoryStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private  int NUM_ITEMS = 7;

        public BlogCategoryStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return BlogCategoryFragment.addBlogCategory("1","yy");
                    //break;
                case 1:
                    return BlogCategoryFragment.addBlogCategory("2","tt");
                    //break;
                .........
                case 6:
                    return BlogCategoryFragment.addBlogCategory("7","gg");
                    //break;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
            //return  fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 7 total pages.
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_general_category);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_county_category);
                 ......
                case 6:
                    return getString(R.string.title_lifestyle_category);
            }
            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

**BlogCategoryFragment**

```
public class BlogCategoryFragment extends Fragment {
    boolean dataLoaded = false;
    public static RecyclerView blogRecycleView;
    public static BlogArticleAdapter blogArticleAdapter;
    public static List<BlogModel> blogModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private BlogModel blogModel;
    private Handler mHandler;
    public BlogCategoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static BlogCategoryFragment addBlogCategory(String categoryId, String categoryName) {
        BlogCategoryFragment fragment = new BlogCategoryFragment();
        CATEGORY_ID   = categoryId;
        CATEGORY_NAME = categoryName;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && !dataLoaded){
            //loadBlogPosts;
            loadDataDirect();
            dataLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blog_category,container,false);
        blogRecycleView = (RecyclerView) listView.findViewById(R.id.blogRecyclerView);
        blogArticleAdapter = new BlogArticleAdapter(blogModelList, getActivity());
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        //set the layout manager
        blogRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        blogRecycleView.setAdapter(blogArticleAdapter);
        //blogRecycleView.stopScroll();
        //setup swipe to refresh
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)listView.findViewById(R.id.refreshBlogLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark
                ,android.R.color.holo_orange_dark ,android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //clear list
                blogModelList.clear();
                loadDataDirect();
                //new LoadBlogPost(BlogCategoryFragment.this).execute(AppConstants.API_BLOG_URL);
                //reload from the internet
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                if (new AppHelper(getActivity()).isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    //loadBlogPosts();
                    loadDataDirect();
                    blogModelList.clear();
                    //new LoadBlogPost(BlogCategoryFragment.this).execute(AppConstants.API_BLOG_URL);
                }  else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        //end setup swipe to refresh
        //loadBlogPosts();
        loadDataDirect();
       //new LoadBlogPost(BlogCategoryFragment.this).execute(AppConstants.API_BLOG_URL);

        return listView;
    }
    private void loadDataDirect(){
        // should be a singleton
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(AppConstants.API_BLOG_URL)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    String responseData = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(responseData);
                    JSONArray blogArticlesArray = jObject.getJSONArray("blog_article");
                    blogModelList.clear();
                    Log.d("BLOG", blogArticlesArray.toString());
                    //create an empty Blogmodel object


                    //loop though the data
                    for (int i = 0; i < blogArticlesArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject blogItem = blogArticlesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        blogModel = new BlogModel(
                                blogItem.getInt("id"),
                                blogItem.getString("article_title"),
                                blogItem.getString("images_url"),
                                blogItem.getString("created_at")
                        );
                        blogModelList.add(blogModel);
                        //update the BlogModel List
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                blogArticleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });



                    }
                    //end loop
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Where could be the issue ?

Comment: your list is null.

Comment: Can we say the list is null yet list items can be seen in other tabs?

Comment: No its not possible

Comment: Use bundle to pass data into fragment. Constructor is bad idea for passing data in fragment.

Comment: I can't see ``CATEGORY_ID`` or ``CATEGORY_NAME`` I guess they are static variables somewhere. You shouldn't use static variables if you are going to have multiple instance of that fragment and you are recreating each page every time.

Comment: I wonder, why are you using `mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` inside `onPageSelected(int position)` ?

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo ,I removed any static methods and properties.Everything is working as it should be though there is a random error which reloads the parent activity of `BlogActivity` when I scroll fast.